# IF-Conditions in XSLT

Tags: xslt, bi-publisher

I do not understand why the following code is not working in an XSL-FO sheet.

In that line:

```
<xsl:when test="xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'Deadline_Year')" < "xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'Last_Year')">
```

I get the error:

> (Fatal Error) Whitespace requirede.

**My code is:**

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'Deadline_Year')" &lt; "xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'Last_Year')">
    <xsl:value-of select="xdoxslt:ifelse(xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'Calc_Year')  xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'Years')> 
            xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'Last_Year'),'',xdoxslt:ifelse(xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'UEBERNAHME') = 0, 0, . div xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'UEBERNAHME'))), ''"/>
  </xsl:when>   
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="xdoxslt:ifelse(xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'Calc_Year')>xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'Last_Year'),'', xdoxslt:ifelse(xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'UEBERNAHME') = 0, 0,. div doxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'UEBERNAHME'))), '' "/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 2):

Two (syntax) problems:

1. Too many double quotes.
2. `<` should be `&lt;`

Here are corrections for those syntax problems:

```
<xsl:when test="xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'Deadline_Year')
                 &lt; xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'Last_Year')">
```